# SQL Server top function return smallest length string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given this problem

> Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY
>   names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters
>   in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city,
>   choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.
>
> ```
> Input Format
>
> The STATION table is described as follows:
> ```

[image: SQL Table schema]

> where LAT_N is the northern latitude and LONG_W is the western
>   longitude.
>
> ```
> Sample Input
>
> Let's say that CITY only has four entries: DEF, ABC, PQRS and WXY
>
> Sample Output
>
> ABC 3
> PQRS 4
> ```

This is my solution.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CITY, LEN(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN(CITY), CITY ASC;
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CITY, LEN(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN(CITY) DESC;
```

From how I am reading this [W3 schools TOP](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Customers;
```

My solution should work.

However, I am receiving this error.

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 6 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 7 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

Comment: take `LEN(CITY) ` the function to `select` calues from `from` `SELECT TOP 1 *,LEN(CITY) FROM CITY FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN(CITY), CITY ASC;`

Comment: You can only have a single `FROM` clause in your sql statement.  I think you just want `select top 1 *, len(city) from station order by len(city), city` . . .

Comment: @sgeddes       That is close but using that syntax it will also return LAT_N and LAT_W

Comment: @sayth You can `select` any field you want, I was just following your example. 
 If you only want the `city` and the `len()`, then remove `*` from your query -- `select top 1 city, len(city)...`  Best of luck to you learning `sql`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asterisk is used to "select all columns", and if you want to add more columns, the column names and the asterisk have to be separated by a comma. Since you want to explicitly specify the columns, don't use the asterisk. Also: You have used the word `FROM` too often. It must not be used in front of the field names but in front of the table names:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CITY, LEN(CITY) AS LENGTH FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN(CITY), CITY;
SELECT TOP 1 CITY, LEN(CITY) AS LENGTH FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN(CITY) DESC, CITY;
```

And if you want to retrieve both rows with just one query, us a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CITY, LEN(CITY) AS LENGTH FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN(CITY), CITY
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 CITY, LEN(CITY) AS LENGTH FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN(CITY) DESC, CITY;
```

Comment: Thanks you wrote exactly what I was trying to write

Answer (score 1):

The error caused you `len` function might put in the `select` clause instead of `from` clause

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` with *window function* to create row number order by `CITY ASC` (your logic) then get `rn = 1` row.

```
select CITY,LEN(CITY) from (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEN(CITY) ORDER BY CITY ASC) rn 
    FROM STATION 
) t1
where t1.rn =1
```

[sqlfiddle](http://rextester.com/ZXMR16515)

Comment: I just can't provide a limit as 1 or top as 1. These work in all other respects.SELECT CITY, LEN(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN(CITY), CITY ASC;
SELECT CITY, LEN(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LEN(CITY), CITY DESC ;

Comment: The return included the LAT_N and LAT_W. It should just return the CIty and the LEN(CITY)

Comment: You can select your expect columns in `select`  you can see my edit answer @sayth 
 http://rextester.com/RDCA98956

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT CITY, length FROM
(
    select TOP 1 CITY, LEN(CITY) as length
    from STATION
    order by LEN(CITY)
) [Min]
UNION ALL
SELECT CITY, length FROM
(
    select TOP 1 CITY, LEN(CITY) as length
    from STATION
    order by LEN(CITY) desc
) [Max]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 CITY, len(CITY) from STATION order by len(CITY) asc,CITY;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome. When answering an old question please explain in your answer how your answer is an improvement on the existing answers.

Comment: I believe the commenter’s intention was to show that `ASC` is implicit in the first query over the top-voted answer. The second query contains `DESC`, explicit. Points for bringing that awareness!

Answer (score -1):

try,

```
(SELECT city, length(city) 
  FROM station
  WHERE LENGTH(city)=(SELECT MIN(LENGTH(city)) FROM station) ORDER BY city ASC LIMIT 1)
 
 UNION

(SELECT city, length(city) 
  FROM station
  WHERE LENGTH(city)=(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(city)) FROM station) ORDER BY city ASC LIMIT 1) ;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).